# Test explorer tree view in Visual Studio 2015 (à la SharpDevelop)?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, sharpdevelop

I have just started using Visual Studio 2015 after having used SharpDevelop for several months. One of the things I miss the most is the tree view of the unit tests (Nunit in my case, with the TestAdapter working OK to show the tests in the test explorer). I am used to write the tests a in a separate assembly mirroring the folder and file structure of the project to test, so a tree view in the test explorer should be something natural, the same way a tree view is natural in the solution explorer.

In this way, I could run a single test, or the tests covering a single class, namespace, project or solution, everything from a single view, no need to be regrouping. But Visual Studio just groups the tests according to a few parameters, so I have to constantly change the grouping. Also, in SharpDevelop the tree nodes were preceded by a green/red dot that allowed you to easily find the failing tests.

So, is there any way to have a tree-view-ish window in Visual Studio 2015, showing the unit tests á la SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in the ReSharper extension, which is paid..  VS'15' (still in beta https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/05/evolving-the-visual-studio-test-platform-part-2/) appears to be almost there with namespace grouping, but still does not look like a full tree functionality. I am also interested in finding a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 I use [AxoCover](https://github.com/axodox/AxoCover) for running Unit Tests. It provides a nice Tree View of the unit tests, grouping by project and namespace. It works with Visual Studio 2012 - 2017. I haven't heard of a 2019 version of AxoCover though. Hope it helps someone else stuck on old versions of Visual Studio.

[image: AxoCover Screenshot]